# Reshaping time series data from wide to long format

Tags: r, time-series, pivot-table

Given time series data of four clients, Client 1,2,3,4.

```
names(data)
"Date" "X1.CLIENT"   "X1seasonal"  "X1trend"  "X1remainder" "X2.CLIENT" 
  "X2seasonal"  "X2trend"     "X2remainder" "X3.CLIENT"   "X3seasonal"  
"X3trend"     "X3remainder" "X4.CLIENT"   "X4seasonal"  "X4trend"     
"X4remainder"
```

Please note that Every Client data is followed by the seasonal, trend and remainder components for the same period of time.

I would like to reshape into long format in a way that looks like

```
"Date" "CLIENT_Number" "Type"  "Value"
```

[Client_Number : 1,2,3,4 ; Type: Client, seasonal, trend, remainder ]

(Additional help to understand : If data(wide format) has 30 rows/instances then we have to convert into long format(30*4*4= 480 rows/instances)

Comment: You could improve this question by showing us a bit of the actual data and improving the formatting. Always check the preview to see what your question is going to look like before finishing it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its just a trivial R programming question, so should be on stackoverflow

Comment: look into `melt` in the `reshape2` package

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your data is an awkward repeated wide format. As ssdecontrol says, use melt from reshape2, I would combine with something like lapply to split into sections. e.g.:

```
# Set up
install.packages("reshape2")
library(reshape2)

# Dummy data
d = data.frame(date=seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"), length.out=100, by=1),
Client.1="A", trend.1=rnorm(100), remainder.1=rpois(10, 3), Client.2="B",
trend.2=rnorm(100), remainder.2=rpois(10, 3), Client.3="C", trend.3=rnorm(100),
remainder.3=rpois(10, 3))

# Split data by columns with client numbers
d = lapply(c(2,5,8), function(i){
    # Take columns relating to client i
    x = d[,c(1, seq(i, length.out=3, by=1))]
    # Rename so you have consistent factor labels
    names(x)[2:4] = c("client", "trend", "remainder")
    # Conververt from wide to long
    x = melt(x, id.vars=c("date", "client"))
})

# Make list into a data frame
d = do.call("rbind", d)
```

I find this post really clear about wide and long formats: http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html